# Ошибка 502 при обновлении asp.net core с 2.0 на 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Обновил проект с 2.0 до 2.1, перекомпилировал проект, запустил и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать? Проект точно компилируется, но запускаться ни в какую не хочет.

Answer (score 2):

Помогла [рекомендация](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/945):

- Откройте командную строку
- Перейдите в каталог bin вашего проекта. Допустим имя вашего проекта 'test'
- Запустите 'dotnet .\test.dll' и вы увидите что-то типа `Microsoft.Aspnetcore.all version 2.1.2 was not found`.
- Запустите `dotnet -info` и вы увидите версию установленного рантайма. В моём случае это был 2.1.1.
  Тогда понизьте пакет Microsoft.Aspnetcore.all к 2.1.1 и всё заработает.
  Альтернативно, можете обновить свою версию рантайма, но это больше мороки :)

У меня было как-то так:

```
C:\...\src\WebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1>dotnet .\Company.ProjName.WebApp.dll
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.1.3' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      2.1.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
```

Откатился с 2.1.3 назад на 2.1.2 - всё заработало.

Странно: студия последняя, со всеми обновлениями.