# Перезалил сайт. Ошибка HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Просто поменял верстку сайта и перезалил, не работает. Никаких пакетов не обновлял. Сегодня сайт перезалил утром, было все ок. Искал в нете ответы, связано с пакетами, но я их не обновлял. В чем проблема может быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это не [обновление пакетов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/872718/213987), то иногда помогает просто перезапуск IIS - где-то встречал такую рекомендацию пока искал про 502.5.

Comment: Перезапуск у меня на компе?

Comment: Знаете, давайте уточним вопрос. Если на компе - то вы запускаете в Visual Studio, там вероятно IIS Express и в нём нет iis reset. А вы пишете "перезалил", что я читаю как "перезалил на хостинг". Так что о чём именно речь? И вообще: я ОЧЕНЬ рекомендую проверить версию с пакетами: дело в том, что первый раз я на неё наткнулся, когда мой хостер обновил с 2.0 до 2.1. И как раз при обращении в поддержку я получил "фигли вы хотели - у 2.0 срок техподдержки в майкрософте закончился и вообще надо порой обновлять окружение". Несовпадение пакетов можно получить и не обновляя пакеты в решении!

Comment: Да,  я перезалил на хостинг. Вот и я удивился вашему ответу, IIS то у меня стоит на компе, какое оно отнешение имеет к серваку на который я перезалил сайт. Сейчас буду пробывать перезаливать пакеты. Возможно ли такое что у меня на днях на винду лицензия щакончилась и на таком компе провожу компиляцию?

Comment: Ну у меня тоже у хостера нет IIS, там nginx под дебианом - так что совет тот я просто вспомнил, раз вы так уверены, что дело не в пакетах. Терзайте хостера на предмет окружения либо сами проверяйте пакеты, если есть доступ на сервер ну или к облачной консоли. А лицензия на винду точно ни при чем, вот уж в чём-чём, а не в этом дело.

Comment: Когда я 2 месяца назад заливал сайт, то была ошибка правда другая...пакет у меня стоял последний а сервак неподдерживал, вот я и установил последнею версию. Сейчас думал может обновился сервак и хоч уобновить тот пакет, но в студии вот так теперь. Раньше этого не было http://prntscr.com/l27pnp

Comment: А приложите к вопросу WebApplication.csproj (меня интересуют ItemGroup где PackageReference и DotNetCliToolReference)

Comment: У меня подобная ошибка была вовсе после переноса проекта с 1 диска на другой (iis/Win). Там оказалось, что у файла оставались старые права, от старой учетной записи, сброс прав помогал решить проблему. Ну а так, я вам советую делать отладку, включите логирование и гляньте, что конкретно не нравиться сайту.

Comment: WebApplication.csproj я если честно не могу понять где найти его

Comment: Перезалил только что резервную версию недельной давности..та же ошибка..скорее всего обнова на серваке о которой не предупредили...имхо

Comment: EvgeniyZ что мы имеете ввиду включить логирование и посмотреть что именно сайту не нравится?

Comment: @FX_Sektor Я про [ASP.NET Core Module stdout log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log), а также про [Enabling the Developer Exception Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.0#enabling-the-developer-exception-page) имел ввиду.